# need to print the result in JAVA script

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface

I am new to Javascript and I need to print the result for a multiplication function.Can you please help me to do that.
Please find the attached image

Following is the code :

```js
function multiply() {
  var a = document.getelemtById("weight").value;
  var b = document.getelemtById("cost").value;
  var myResult = document.getElementById('result');
  var myResult = parseint(a) * parseint(b);
}
```

```html
<span>
  <center>
  <h3> Calculation of Shipping charge </h3>
  <label for = "weight"> Total Prodcut Weight </label>
  <input type = "text" name = "Total Prodcut Weight" id = "weight" > <br>

  <br>

  <label for = "cost" > Shipping cost(per kg) < /label>
  <input type = "text" name = "Shipping cost(per kg)" id = "cost" >
  <br>
  <br>
  <button type = "button" onclick = multiply() > compute </button>

<br>
<div id="result"></div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSNpn.jpg)

Comment: You may have a typo there: "parseint" should be replaced with "parseInt" (the letter i is capitalized)

Comment: Yes.. And there's no such function: getelemtById, One is expected to debug their code for this simple basic type of errors, before asking

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggested, change `getelemtById` to `getElementById` and change `parseint` to `parseInt`. I also changed the `.innerHTML` of `#result` to display the result.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function multiply() {
    var a = document.getElementById("weight").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("cost").value;
    var myResult = document.getElementById('result');
    myResult.innerHTML = parseInt(a) * parseInt(b); // removed var
  }
</script>
<span>
<center>
<h3>Calculation of Shipping charge</h3>
<label for="weight">Total Prodcut Weight</label> <!-- Prodcut should be Product-->
   <input type="text"  name="Total Prodcut Weight" id="weight"><br>

   <br>

       <label for="cost">Shipping cost(per kg)</label>
<input type="text"  name="Shipping cost(per kg)" id="cost">  
<br>
<br>
 <button type="button" onclick=multiply()>compute</button>
</center>
                </span>
<br>
<div id="result">
  <center>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code try

```js
function multiply() {
  var a = document.getElementById("weight").value;
  var b = document.getElementById("cost").value;
  //var myResult = document.getElementById('result');
  var myResult = parseInt(a) * parseInt(b);
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=myResult
  console.log(myResult)
}
```

```html
<h3>Calculation of Shipping charge</h3>
<label for="weight">Total Prodcut Weight</label>
<input type="text" name="Total Prodcut Weight" id="weight"><br>

<br>

<label for="cost">Shipping cost(per kg)</label>
<input type="text" name="Shipping cost(per kg)" id="cost">
<button type="button" onclick=multiply()>compute</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```